# gcc linking in the same lib twice

Tags: gcc, static

This might seem like a strange idea, but I need the same library linked into my code twice.

A bit of background: I am writing a bit of firmware with a bootloader and a application. Both bits of code need to use the comms library (spi) and some other system libs to run. I cannot replace those libraries in the bootloader if it is using those libraries to run. Hence I would like to include the lib twice, once for the bootloader, and once for the application.

Previously I have done this by making two programs and splicing the HEX files as part of the build process. This time I would like to make one elf that contains both application and bootloader (with debugging symbols for both). Then I can generate the boot load image by stripping it out in a post build step. This allows me to build a complete image and use the linker to avoid collisions etc without making my own tool, and means I can debug errors in the bootloader and the application easily, but the only stumbling block would having the lib multiple times

I figure a solution might be to make two separate static libs ie bootloader.a and application.a the both already contain the other lib, but this seems messy. Does anyone know a better solution?

Comment: If it is _one_ binary brick, why include the library _twice_?

Comment: because during the bootload I might want to update for example the comms lib for the application, but as the bootloader also needs this lib it will need its own copy which is not being overwritten

Comment: hmm I just thought of a good way to do this but am un-sure if gcc supports it. If I could set the name mangling prefix manually like is done for statics automatically I could compile different version of the libs with differing symbol names and everything would work great.